(Facepunch.Steamworks) EntryPointNotFoundException on SteamAPI_Init (using latest Steamworks SDK)
I'm getting this error when I try to test my Unity game (using Facepunch.Steamworks) while Steam is open (just implemented achievements and I want to test them). Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SteamAPI_Init assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Steamworks.SteamAPI+Native.SteamAPI_Init()
  at Steamworks.SteamAPI.Init () [0x00001] in D:\STEAMWORKS_FACEPUNCH\Facepunch.Steamworks\Classes\SteamApi.cs:31 
  at Steamworks.SteamClient.Init (System.UInt32 appid, System.Boolean asyncCallbacks) [0x00039] in D:\STEAMWORKS_FACEPUNCH\Facepunch.Steamworks\SteamClient.cs:26 

This is the code that's causing the problem:
public void Init()
{
    if (hasAlreadyInitiated) return;
    this.Log("Init has been called");
    try
    {

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if(forceDemoAppID)
    {
        SteamClient.Init(FAUNAMORPH_DEMO_APP_ID);
    }
    else if(forceMainAppID)
    {
        SteamClient.Init(FAUNAMORPH_APP_ID);
    }
    else
    {
#endif
#if DEMO_STEAM
        SteamClient.Init(DEMO_APP_ID);
#else
        SteamClient.Init(MAIN_APP_ID);
#endif
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    }
#endif

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        IsSteamClientOpen = true;
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        this.Log($"{("Couldn't initialize Steam Client").Bold().Color(Color.red)}. Error: {e}");
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    IsSteamClientOpen = false;
    }
    hasAlreadyInitiated = true;
}

I'm using the latest version of Facepunch (compiled from source), and the most recent version of  Steamworks SDK (1.60).
The error happens when I call SteamClient.Init(appId) at the very start of the game (code snapshot below - in this case, neither forceDemoAppID or forceMainAppID are active, but it still happens when either is active)

Here you can find some tips

@MichałTurczyn I don't quite understand how that can help me in this situation, since I'm using a C# wrapper for the Steamworks SDK. I've read through it and still didn't understood how to apply to my scenario
